# Efficient Power Iteration for largest and smallest eigenvalue

Tags: algorithm, matlab, eigenvalue

I am preparing for my numerics exam in a couple of days and had an old exam asking to implement a search for the largest and the smallest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix in one MATLAB-function, without of course using *eig(A)*.   Now are neither the power method nor the inverse power method a problem to be implemented standing alone, but there is one specification in the question I cannot really get:

> You should access the elements of A as few times as possible.

Does there exist a trick how to get the following code snippet, using the power iteration method, calculate the smallest value as efficient as possible?

Attached code excerpt for power method:

```
while error > tol
  i = i + 1;
  y_k = z_k/norm(z_k);
  z_new = A*y_k;
  mu_k = transpose(y_k)*z_new;

  %mu_small = transpose(y_small)*z_newsmal;

  error = abs(mu_k - mu_old);
  mu_old = mu_k;
  z_k =  z_new;
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: is that statement hinting you to use a different method? Or do you know for sure that this algorithm you just posted is the one you want?

Comment: Mhh, we also shortly talked about the Shifted Power Iteration, but since it was explicitly mentioned to calculate the largest and smallest I think that wouldn't be more efficient than doing the Power and Inverse Power Method.

Comment: I have no idea about methods for solving eig (I forgot most of What I knew), but this seem like a question with a "trick" to fool students. I assume you need to choose the method that makes sure that you access `A` less, not the one that is "more efficient". That said, I don't know your profesor, so I might be wrong.